# How do I add a validation rule or input mask that ensures the textbox input is exactly 11 characters long in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, validation

I am trying to ensure a text box in MS Access 2007 matches an employer reference number so I have used the "Input Mask":

```
    >###\/??#####;;_
```

This works apart from it allows you to enter half the reference number (say the first 3 numbers only) so I wanted to use a validation rule to ensure that the length of the input is exactly 11 character (including the "/").

I have tried the validation rule:

```
    =Len([EmployerRefNum])=11
```

BUT this seems to always cause the validation to fail. I have even tried removing the Input Mask and JUST having the validation rule then typing 11 chracters and this still fails.

P.S. I really also need to to be 0 or 11 character to allow for them to leave it blank encase they don't have the employer reference number with them currently I suspect once I have the valid 11 characters code I could do an OR(,) with the same code and 0 instead of 11.

Comment: I tried with the validation rule, and it worked (A2003). Maybe you should try again using a control name that is different from the field name, and refer to the control name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the different elements are required, not optional, why not use this for the input mask:

```
000\/LL00000;;_
```

Comment: Is there anyway of including the "/" e.g. "123/AB12345" in the value that gets saved to the DB? At the moment it only saves the "123AB12345"?

Comment: Oh got it! :) Aparently it needed the second peramiter to be 0 like this:
        >000\/LL00000;0;_

Comment: Correct. If you didn't know already, you can click inside the InputMask property and hit F1 to get some very useful information. :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be that your `EmployerRefNum` is interpreted as a number instead of a string, so the `Len()` will not work.

Maybe you could try something like:

```
  Is Null Or Len(CStr(Nz([EmployerRefNum]))) = 11
```

That will pass if the field is left blank or if the length of the data in exactly 11.

As [Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408736/how-do-i-add-a-validation-rule-that-ensures-the-textbox-input-is-exactly-11-chara/6409572#6409572) said, you may be better off solving this issue using a combobox or validating your input from code if you really want to use a textbox and catch all possible user errors.

Validation fields and masks are really not user-friendly and not that flexible: you often spend more time trying to craft a properly working validation and mask than it would take to do it in VBA.

Using code you also have the luxury of informing the user in a nicer way than the horrible and verbose dialog box that pops up when the validation fails.

For instance, you could highlight the `EmployerRefNum` texbox in red when it fails validation:

```vb
Private Function IsValidEmployerRefNum() As Boolean
    IsValidEmployerRefNum = IsNull(EmployerRefNum) _
                            Or Len(CStr(Nz(EmployerRefNum))) = 11
End Function

Private Sub EmployerRefNum_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    EmployerRefNum.BackColor = Iif(IsValidEmployerRefNum(), vbWhite, vbRed)
End Sub

Public Function IsAllValid() As Boolean
    IsAllValid = IsValidEmployerRefNum() _
                 And IsValidMyOtherField() _
                 And IsValidYetAnotherField()
End Function
```

You can do complex validation logic in the `IsAllValid()` function and use that to allow the data to be saved at the form-level or not:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not IsValid()
End Sub
```

There are many ways to do these things, this is not meant to be a good example, there are lots of ways to make this better, but this can get you started.

Having your validation rules in code also have the advantage that they are in the same place rather than be scattered in controls and forms all over the place.
Ideally, you should even centralise all your validation rules in modules or classes as they are part of your business logic.
Keeping them in one place makes maintaining your code much easier as Business rules always change over time.

Comment: No it's not having it. It doesn't like the "Is Null" first then if I just use "Len(CStr(Nz([EmployerRefNum]))) = 11" or even "Len(CStr(Nz([EmployerRefNum]))) > 1" it is still alwasy failing. Also it alwasy adds an "=" to the start. It's like it it checking if the output from the textbox is equal to the out put from the validation code!

Comment: Oh you've added to your answer! I like the second section. Will have a look into that VBA option. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer for pointing out that input masks are fussy and often more trouble than they are worth. However, I still use them for dates (requiring 4 digits). That's about the only time I ever use them, though. The one advantage is the indication onscreen of the expected input format, as well as the saving of characters being typed in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a combobox with the employee list? This is the only way to make sure that data entered refers to a valid employee reference ...

Comment: Thanks but that won't work as we are entering the reference into the system for the first time at this point. :) It's an external reference number.

Comment: Well then you are then entering a very hazardeous process, where you will not have the possibility to implement your 'de facto' integrity rule for your employee reference numbers in your database.

Comment: I am not sure I follow? All data has to be entered into a system at some point! ;) This data is given to us by our clients in the form of faxes normally (aparently some industrys are still stuck in the stone age! ;)) and as it's only known by them we can't really get a perfect list in the system. Think of it as a reference the customers have that they want us to give them back when we refer to a certain case. :)

Comment: Philippe is right that if you know control the data that need to be input it's better to allow the user to choose from a combobox (especially since they implement autotype), but in your case you don't have much choice. I would still go with VBA though as it's more flexible in the long run and generally easier to maintain should the rules change.